# HTML canvas drawing and erasing with transparent png base

Tags: javascript, canvas, drawing

Here is a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/g10qgefy/46/

```
if (drawingMode === 'brush') {
      ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-atop";

    } else { //erase
      ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
      ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(1,0,0,0)';
    }
```

I am trying to create this simple drawing feature. I have a canvas element, I draw an image to it using `drawImage()`. Then, you can brush on the non-transparent pixels using canvas method `globalCompositeOperation = "source-atop"`.

That all does what I want. But I also need to be able to erase some of the drawn lines without affecting the transparent image. So I just want to select the erase button and start erasing away the black lines I have drawn.

I have been playing with globalCompositionOperation and changing the values from [Canvas Rendering | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation) but these mostly just delete everything.

I'm sure there is a solution - would love to hear your thoughts!

Answer (score 4):

Keep two layers: the one the user is drawing to, and the rendering one.

Draw the user's drawings on the first layer (offscreen canvas) and then do your compositing with the png image on top of this layer on a second canvas, the rendering one.

This way you can perform your erase calls safely, without having to care about the png layer.

```js
let renderingElement = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
// create an offscreen canvas only for the drawings
let drawingElement = renderingElement.cloneNode();
let drawingCtx = drawingElement.getContext('2d');
let renderingCtx = renderingElement.getContext('2d');


let img = new Image();
let brushSize = 25;
let brushColor = "#000000"
let drawingMode = 'brush';

let lastX;
let lastY;
let moving = false;

img.src = 'https://i.pinimg.com/originals/49/af/b1/49afb1d21ae594cb7ac3534a15383711.png';
img.onload = () => {
  renderingCtx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
}

let eraseButton = document.getElementById('erase');
let brushButton = document.getElementById('brush');
let exportButton = document.getElementById('export');

eraseButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  drawingMode = 'erase';
})

brushButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  drawingMode = 'brush';
})

renderingElement.addEventListener('mousedown', (ev) => {
  moving = true;
  lastX = ev.pageX - renderingElement.offsetLeft;
  lastY = ev.pageY - renderingElement.offsetTop;
})

renderingElement.addEventListener('mouseup', (ev) => {
  moving = false;
  lastX = ev.pageX - renderingElement.offsetLeft;
  lastY = ev.pageY - renderingElement.offsetTop;
})

renderingElement.addEventListener('mousemove', (ev) => {
  if (moving) {
    if (drawingMode === 'brush') {
      drawingCtx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
    } else {
      drawingCtx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
    }
    let currentX = ev.pageX - renderingElement.offsetLeft;
    let currentY = ev.pageY - renderingElement.offsetTop;

    drawingCtx.beginPath();
    drawingCtx.lineJoin = "round";
    drawingCtx.moveTo(lastX, lastY);
    drawingCtx.lineTo(currentX, currentY);
    drawingCtx.closePath();
    drawingCtx.strokeStyle = brushColor;
    drawingCtx.lineWidth = brushSize;
    drawingCtx.stroke();

    lastX = currentX;
    lastY = currentY;

    // draw to visible canvas
    renderingCtx.clearRect(0, 0, renderingElement.width, renderingElement.height);
    renderingCtx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    renderingCtx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';
    renderingCtx.drawImage(drawingElement, 0, 0);
    
    // reset
    renderingCtx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
  }

});
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<button id="brush">brush</button>
<button id="erase">erase</button>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need! Working perfect, thank you

Answer (score 1):

When erasing simply set your current brush as a [*pattern*](https://devdocs.io/dom/canvasrenderingcontext2d/createpattern) (with no repeat) using the original image, or to work around most caveats (scale, translate etc.): define the initial canvas (with the image drawn in) as the pattern and store the pattern globally (shown in the modified code below).

**Update** Although this is correct code-wise, it turns out some browsers currently has issues with using the canvas element as pattern source (a browser bug, in this case FF v59 on osX, ref. Kaiido's comment).

No worries though, there is a simple workaround for this though: just use the original image instead of canvas for the pattern (as shown below - code example updated). *******

This will allow you to draw back portions of the image using the same compositing mode as before.

```
// define and set brush
let pattern = ctx.createPattern(img, "no-repeat");
ctx.strokeStyle = pattern;
```

```js
let canvasElement = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
let img = new Image();
let brushSize = 25;
let brushColor = "#000000"
let drawingMode = 'brush';
let ctx = canvasElement.getContext('2d');
let lastX;
let lastY;
let moving = false;
let pattern;

img.src = 'https://i.pinimg.com/originals/49/af/b1/49afb1d21ae594cb7ac3534a15383711.png';
img.onload = () => {
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-atop";
  pattern = ctx.createPattern(img, "no-repeat");
}

let eraseButton = document.getElementById('erase');
let brushButton = document.getElementById('brush');

eraseButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  drawingMode = 'erase';
  ctx.strokeStyle = pattern; // use pattern for style here
})

brushButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  drawingMode = 'brush';
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#000";                       // restore current color here
})

canvasElement.addEventListener('mousedown', (ev) => {
  moving = true;
  lastX = ev.pageX;
  lastY = ev.pageY;
})

canvasElement.addEventListener('mouseup', (ev) => {
  moving = false;
  lastX = ev.pageX;
  lastY = ev.pageY;
})

canvasElement.addEventListener('mousemove', (ev) => {
  if (moving) {
    let currentX = ev.pageX;
    let currentY = ev.pageY;

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineJoin = "round";
    ctx.moveTo(lastX, lastY);
    ctx.lineTo(currentX, currentY);
    ctx.closePath();
    //ctx.strokeStyle = brushColor; // can be set during color selecting (if mode=draw)
    ctx.lineWidth = brushSize;
    ctx.stroke();

    lastX = currentX;
    lastY = currentY;
  }

})
```

```css
canvas {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  border: 5px solid red;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 550px;
}

#erase {
  left: 60px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>

<button id="brush">
brush
</button>

<button id="erase">
erase
</button>
```

Comment: Good idea, but somehow, the example doesn't work on my FF. ...what a weird bug... It doesn't render until we force a layout reflow.

Comment: On mine I have to force this reflow (e.g right click - Inspect) and then it will work normally, until then, only the png is drawn. Might be an issue with mine only.

Comment: @kaiido "Might be an issue with mine only." Probably is - works in every browser I tested with here so this is likely a bug in your version. What version/OS do you use? Have you updated to recent version?

Comment: I'm on beta 59 on osX. Just tried on Nightly 60 and same issue. I'll have to file a bug when I'll get time. I can repro the bug in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/357rtbvg/), while [this one](https://jsfiddle.net/357rtbvg/1/) works... => when nothing is drawn after `createPattern`, the rendering is blocked and out of stream calls are not rendered. If anything is drawn after createPattern in the same loop, all is ok. (just tried in your snippet and indeed, calling drawImage once again after createPattern worksaround the bug...)

Comment: @Kaiido and if the pattern is defined using the original image instead of the canvas element?

Comment: Han, I had an old 57 stable version where the bug occurred too, after updating to stable 58 it works there. Yes using the `<img>` as pattern-source also works.

Comment: Perfect that's exactly what I needed. Thanks guys appreciate your time.