# Fabric.js clipping free drawing with PNG image

Tags: fabricjs

Using [Fabric.js](https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js), I'm trying to do free drawing on the **non-transparent parts only** of a .PNG image.

I tried 2 things without success. The drawing is still appearing on the transparent pixel of the image.

#### 1. Using *globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop'*

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
canvas.backgroundColor = '#ffffff';

fabric.Image.fromURL('https://i.pinimg.com/originals/49/af/b1/49afb1d21ae594cb7ac3534a15383711.png', function (myImg) {
    var img1 = myImg.set({ left: 0, top: 0, width: 503, height: 343 });
    canvas.add(img1);
});

canvas.isDrawingMode = 1;
canvas.getContext().globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';
canvas.freeDrawingBrush.color = "purple";
canvas.freeDrawingBrush.width = 10;
canvas.renderAll();
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400" class="canvas"></canvas>
```

#### 2. Using clipping

```js
var canvas;

$(function () {
    canvas = window._canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
    canvas.backgroundColor = '#efefef';
    canvas.isDrawingMode= 1;
    canvas.freeDrawingBrush.color = "purple";
    canvas.freeDrawingBrush.width = 10;
     var imgInstance = fabric.Image.fromURL('https://i.pinimg.com/originals/49/af/b1/49afb1d21ae594cb7ac3534a15383711.png', function (img) {
        canvas.add(img);
        canvas.renderAll();
    });
 
    canvas.renderAll();

    canvas.on("path:created", (e) => {
      var path = e.path;
      path.set({selectable:false})
      path.clipPath = imgInstance;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400" class="canvas"></canvas>
```

Clipping with Objects works but not with a PNG image. I could also find a solution when working with native canvas like it's described in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49228110/6660372). They are using a concept of 2 contexts. But I really need to make it work with Fabric.js.

Any help would be really appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: For the ones who are stuck on this as well... As I could not find any solutions for this, I had to look for another library able to handle this problem. I found Konvajs that suit perfectly.